# Terraform Custom Provider: How to avoid TF state file updates in case remote URL is unavailable?

Tags: go, terraform

I am writing a custom terraform provider and have followed all the documented steps in the following URL: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/development/writing-custom-terraform-providers

I am able to get it running with all the CRUD operations with an SDK used for remote service where I am triggering API calls.

However, one issue I am facing is that in case remote URL is unavailable, running a `terraform apply` overwrites the TF state file even though I am returning an error from the plugin. This error is also reflected in the `terraform apply` output.

**Edit:**
Looks like I found steps to replicate this with an existing repository: https://github.com/Mastercard/terraform-provider-restapi/

Observations from this:

1. If I use the latest release binary from https://github.com/Mastercard/terraform-provider-restapi/releases, it works as expected.
2. If I clone the repository and build the binary myself using this command `go build -o terraform-provider-restapi_v1.10.0-linux-amd64`, I start getting the errors as mentioned in the question.
   go version: `go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64`

What am I doing wrong here? How do we build provider binaries?

Any help on how to correct this?

Comment: Can you share the error you get? This is going to be hard to diagnose without seeing your provider code but Terraform shouldn't update the state file for a resource if that resource errors. If your provider can be shared publicly that would also help.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The error is the custom API error for failed calls as remote service is unavailable. From the documentation, I see the recommendation to return errors back and TF will take care of this. Unfortunately, I can't share the code publicly. Let me know if there is any specific detail I can share which can be helpful.

Comment: If you're returning the errors back to Terraform then this should be fine. If you're just returning nil, nil on a read (no resource ID and no error) then yes, that's how Terraform knows that something has been deleted from the provider's endpoint.

Comment: If you want this answering, you'd have to share your read code really. Or at least something that works as a [mcve] that exhibits the same behaviour even if it's not the same code. If you can't share that then this is probably unanswerable just as if you had asked any other programming question and are unable to share the code.

Comment: Sure, let me try and create an MRE for this. Will share here.

Comment: Terraform can potentially update the state on error in some cases, to account for situations where the operation has _partially_ succeeded and so the provider needs to track that partial result. I'm rusty on what cases cause the SDK to activate that mode, but IIRC it has something to do with `d.Partial` and `d.SetPartial`. A full example would help to guide some poking into the SDK code though, indeed.

Comment: Added details in question. See if it helps.